# Time nonce generation in go routines

Tags: go, http-headers, goroutine, nonce

I am calling rest api which expects nonce header. The nonce must be unique timestamp and every consecutive call should have *timestamp > previous one*. My goal is to launch 10 go routines and from each one do a call to the web api. Since we do not have control over the routine execution order we might end up doing a webapi call with a *nonce < previous one*. I do not have control over the api implementation.

I have stripped down my code to something very simple which illustrate the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    count := 10
    results := make(chan string, count)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go someWork(results)
        // Enabling the following line would give the 
        // expected outcome but does look like a hack to me.
        // time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    }

    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-results)
    }
}

func someWork(done chan string) {
    // prepare http request, do http request, send to done chan the result
    done <- time.Now().Format("15:04:05.00000")
}
```

From the output you can see how we have timestamps which are not chronologically ordered:

```
13:18:26.98549
13:18:26.98560
13:18:26.98561
13:18:26.98553
13:18:26.98556
13:18:26.98556
13:18:26.98557
13:18:26.98558
13:18:26.98559
13:18:26.98555
```

What would be the idiomatic way to achieve the expected outcome without adding the *sleep* line?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is bit complicated. I'm thinking about how API will return response. Will your API's return response in sequential order?

Comment: The API response is irrelevant. The idea is to post 10 requests and ignore the responses.

Comment: so what do you mean by chronologically ordered?

Comment: In the sample output as you can see the timestamps are not in ascending order.

Comment: You are trying to make the requests concurrently, why would you expect these to be ordered at all? If you need them to be called in order, you can't execute them concurrently. `Sleep` does not guarantee the order either, it just happens to appear that way for this particular example.

Comment: @JimB I agree the `Sleep` is not an option. Also I don't want to execute them synchronously because I would have to wait for each response before executing the next request. There should be a simple way to execute all the request in parallel with specific order. Imagine each response takes 1h, but I can call all endpoints within 1 second I forget about the response.

Comment: “in parallel with specific order” does not make sense. To have a defined order the requests must be sent in that order. If the requests are long, you would need to organize some sort of callback to dispatch the next request after each was received, but this would still be synchronous to define an order.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you only need to synchronize (serialize) the goroutines till request send part, that is where the timestamp and nonce need to be sequential. Response processing can be in parallel.

You can use a mutex for this case like in below code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    count := 10
    results := make(chan string, count)
    var mutex sync.Mutex
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        go someWork(&mutex, results)
    }

    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-results)
    }
}

func someWork(mut *sync.Mutex, done chan string) {
    // Lock the mutex, go routine getting lock here, 
    // is guaranteed to create the timestamp and 
    // perform the request before any other
    mut.Lock()
    // Get the timestamp
    myTimeStamp := time.Now().Format("15:04:05.00000")
    // prepare http request, do http request
    // Unlock the mutex
    mut.Unlock()

    // Process response
    // send to done chan the result
    done <- myTimeStamp
}
```

But still some duplicate timestamps, may be need more fine-grained timestamp, but that is up to the use case.

Comment: The mutex does nothing here, it only happens to slow things down enough the appear ordered in this oversimplified example.

Comment: Mutex them happen in order, as OP required `consecutive call should have timestamp > previous one`.  In a way `slow things down enough`, yes. Better than sending requests without using gorotuines

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants then because the requests are not returning immediately, but at least the requests could be made in order. The output will not be ordered, because the goroutines may send back results in any order, but that shouldn't matter here.

Answer (score 0):

I think: you can use a WaitGroup, for example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup = sync.WaitGroup{}
var ct int = 0

func hello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello Go %v\n", time.Now().Format("15:04:05.00000"))
    // when you are done, call done:
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(10 * int(time.Second)))
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go hello()
        wg.Wait()
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes but that would wait for the routine to receive the api response before launching the next routine. What I am actually trying to achieve is to launch 10 api calls almost simultaneously regardless of their time to respond.

Comment: then put the last wg.Wait() outside of the for

Comment: Moving it out makes your code sample no different then mine. Maybe not very obvious but you could try by adding more zeros to the time format `.Format("15:04:05.0000000")`